# Parse xml file into collection

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, collections

I have an interface in type of

```
public interface ICollectionInterfaceTestConfig
{

    [Option(DefaultValue = "Simple object")]

    string SimpleObject { get; set; }

    ICollection<ITestDerivedConfig> TestDerivedConfigCollection { get; set; }
}
```

And xml file with same structure.
How i can parse xml file into collection of ITestDerivedConfig

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: as far as I know, you can't initialize interfaces. That's the problem